# How do i get the python Discord module in Atom?

Tags: python, discord.py, atom-editor

I'm trying to code a discord bot using atom. Although I've run the command to install discord.py (python3 -m pip install -U discord.py) and typed "import discord" in my code, Atom still says "no module named discord." Is there like an atom package or something else that i need to install to be able to code discord bots through atom?

Comment: Discord.py is shutting down, you should move on to a fork of it or use slash commands.

Comment: it’s not shutting down, it’s simply not gonna be developer any more, though for the next few months it’ll work flawlessly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you code editor to something else, from what you have stated, you have installed the package yet it is not picking it up. The only thing other than changing your editor would be to try restarting your pc. There is really nothing I can think of that could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio Code and I had the same problem. A Virtual Environment (Venv) helped me. [Here is the link to venv's for atom](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-virtualenv)